# Placing Image into Center of Pie Chart

Tags: plotting, image

The following code

```
bidenNicheBreakdown = {20, 80};
bidenImage = 
  Rasterize[(WebImageSearch["Joe Biden"] // Normal // 
      First )[["Thumbnail"]], ImageSize -> Tiny];
bidenTitle =  
  ToString[bidenImage, StandardForm] <> "\nVoter Breakdown: Joe Biden";
bidenNicheChart = 
 PieChart[bidenNicheBreakdown, 
  ChartLegends -> {"Leftist", "Moderate"}, PlotTheme -> "Web", 
  Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> False, PlotLabel -> bidenTitle, 
  ChartLabels -> bidenNicheBreakdown]
```

yields

> [image]

**Question 1:** Instead of placing the photo of Joe Biden *on top* of the pie chart, how can I force it to be in *the center* of the pie chart (and small enough so that it doesn't obstruct the numbers)?

**Question 2:** If I end up having several of these charts (one for each Democratic primary candidate), is there a command that would allow me to present them in one large image as a *grid* of images (suitably large enough/rich enough in quality so that someone could see all of their numeric detail when the image is blown up)?

**EDIT:** I've discovered `Grid[]`. Is there a way to ensure that each element in the grid is larger?

> [image]

Comment: Q1: Look up `Inset`. Starting point: add `Epilog -> {Inset[bidenImage]}`. Q2: Did you try `Grid`?

Answer (score 5):

An alternative way to place images in the middle of the chart to avoid occlusion of labels is (1)  to prepend the input data with the trivial dataset (`{1}`) and (2) to use a custom `ChartElementFunction` to use images as texture for the sector polygons.

To use images as texture for sectors we slightly modify the built-in (but undocumented) chart element function `` System`BarFunctionDump`TextureRadius ``:

```
ClearAll[txtrBar, cEF]
txtrBar[t_] :=  System`BarFunctionDump`TextureRadius[#, #2, "Placement" -> "Fill"] /. 
        Texture[_] :> t &;

cEF[cedf_: ChartElementData["Sector"]] := If[#3 === {}, cedf[##], #3[[1]][##]] &
```

**Examples:**

```
data = {{10, 20}, {40, 60}, {50, 20, 10}};

images = ExampleData[{"TestImage", #}] & /@ {"Lena", "Girl3", "Mandrill"};

dataandimages = MapThread[{{1 -> txtrBar[Texture @ #2]}, 
     Labeled[#, Style[#, 16]] & /@ #} &, {data, images}];

charts = PieChart[#, ChartStyle -> 97, ImageSize -> 300, 
     SectorSpacing -> .25, ChartElementFunction -> cEF[]] & /@ dataandimages;

Legended[Row[charts], 
  Placed[SwatchLegend[97, "legend label" <> ToString[#] & /@ {1, 2, 3}], Right]]
```

[image]

Change `cEF[]` to `cEF[ChartElementData["OscillatingSector", "AngularFrequency" -> 15, "RadialAmplitude" -> 0.1]` to get

[image]

Replace `"OscillatingSector"` with  `"NoiseSector"`  to get:

[image]

```
fifteencharts = RandomChoice[Show[#, ImageSize -> 150]& /@ charts, 15];
legend = SwatchLegend[97, "legend label" <> ToString[#] & /@ {1, 2, 3}, 
  LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}];

Legended[Grid[Partition[fifteencharts, 5]], Placed[legend, Top]
```

[image]

```
Panel[Grid[Partition[fifteencharts, 5]], legend]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also

1. Crop the images *circularly* using a combination of `Texture`
   and `CirclePoints`,
2. Make room in the center of the chart using the second element of the
   option setting `SectorOrigin`, e.g., `SectorOrigin -> {{0, 1}, 1}`
3. Use the resulting images as  `Epilog` in `PieChart`

```
data = {{10, 20}, {40, 60}, {50, 20, 10}};

images = ExampleData[{"TestImage", #}] & /@ {"Lena", "Girl3", "Mandrill"};

epilogs = {EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[10], White}], Texture[#], 
  Polygon[CirclePoints[50], VertexTextureCoordinates -> Automatic]} & /@ images;

Graphics /@ epilogs // Row
```

[image]

```
charts = MapThread[
   PieChart[#, ChartLabels -> #, ChartStyle -> 97, LabelStyle -> 16, 
     ImageSize -> 300, SectorOrigin -> {{0, 1}, 1},
     ChartElementFunction -> "OscillatingSector", 
     Epilog -> #2] &, 
  {data, epilogs}];

legend = SwatchLegend[97, "legend label" <> ToString[#] & /@ {1, 2, 3}, 
     LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}];

Legended[Row[charts], Placed[legend, Top]]
```

[image]